# Documentation flags should support Markdown

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I just noticed this on one of the examples that I flagged:

[image: Lack of Markup indicated by freehand red lines.]

Is there a reason why [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) isn't supported here? Granted, the comments in the image above might not be the best example (I personally like to use emphasis though), but using code markup in particular would make these a lot more readable.

Plus all of the other reasons Markdown is allowed in Q&A comments...